# keras for R-windows, without installing anaconda(python 3 is preinstalled)

Tags: python, r, keras

im trying to install keras for R, for Windows System, and python3 is already pre-installed, i was wondering if they is a way to install keras without installing anaconda ?and only for CPu(Not for GPU), because my Company doesnt have access to anaconda, and i Need keras to complete my Project, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Looks like it is possible without Anaconda - the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/#installation) recommends using [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/), and the R instructions for RStudio are [here](https://keras.rstudio.com).

Comment: eventually [install_keras()](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/install_keras.htmlhttps://keras.rstudio.com/reference/install_keras.htmlhttps://keras.rstudio.com/reference/install_keras.html)  will look for virtual environment in anaconda then it is probably gonna prompt to use anaconda.

Comment: well, anaconda is free and open source

Comment: @heisenbug47, so ist not possible to do it without anaconda ?

Comment: @bob1, i tried that, but still its showing error and asking to install anaconda

Comment: @jai, I fear so. `"Keras and TensorFlow will be installed into an "r-tensorflow" virtual or conda environment. Note that "virtualenv" is not available on Windows (as this isn't supported by TensorFlow)" `. This is documented [here](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/install_keras.html).